KeyError: 'base_model.model.model.layers.0.mlp.down_proj.lora_A.weight'
I finetune mistral7b and I try to load it my finetune model into my application but I keep getting this mistake:error
do anyone know where it come from, my finetuning work well ( with axolotl project and pet.py), a month ago everything works well with this config
My config for finetuning :
base_model: mistralai/Mistral-7B-v0.1
model_type: MistralForCausalLM
tokenizer_type: LlamaTokenizer
is_mistral_derived_model: true
hub_model_id: DevSelego/Mistral7b_summarizer_v5

load_in_8bit: false
load_in_4bit: true
strict: false
datasets:
  - path: DevSelego/jobmaker_summarize_v5
    type: alpaca
dataset_prepared_path: last_run_prepared
val_set_size: 0.05
output_dir: ./qlora-out

adapter: qlora
lora_model_dir:

sequence_len: 8192
sample_packing: false
pad_to_sequence_len: true

lora_r: 32
lora_alpha: 16
lora_dropout: 0.05
lora_target_linear: true
lora_fan_in_fan_out:
lora_target_modules:
  - gate_proj
  - down_proj
  - up_proj
  - q_proj
  - v_proj
  - k_proj
  - o_proj

wandb_project: Mistral_Jobmaker
wandb_entity:
wandb_watch:
wandb_name:
wandb_log_model:

gradient_accumulation_steps: 1
micro_batch_size: 10
num_epochs: 1
optimizer: adamw_bnb_8bit
lr_scheduler: cosine
learning_rate: 0.0002

train_on_inputs: false
group_by_length: false
bf16: true
fp16: false
tf32: false

gradient_checkpointing: true
early_stopping_patience:
resume_from_checkpoint:
local_rank:
logging_steps: 1
xformers_attention:
flash_attention: true

loss_watchdog_threshold: 5.0
loss_watchdog_patience: 3

warmup_steps: 10
eval_steps: 0.05
eval_table_size:
eval_table_max_new_tokens: 128
save_steps:
debug:
deepspeed:
weight_decay: 0.0
fsdp:
fsdp_config:
special_tokens:
  bos_token: "<s>"
  eos_token: "</s>"
  unk_token: "<unk>"


Thanks for your help
help to debug finetuning
